# Send ERC-20 token using Web3j

Tags: ethereum, web3-java

What is the best way to send transaction in Ethereum with ERC-20 token and get balance of account using web3j

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/blk-io/erc20-rest-service it will proxy requests into an ERC20 contract.